# knitr 2 wordpress (sends title no content)

Tags: r, knitr

I am attempting to use knitr to WordPress just to demo it as [seen here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/).  Here is a script I am attempting to use.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/Errors/post.txt

I encountered the problem where the post title is sent but not the content.  [Yihui suggested I use debug to step through the problem](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/#comment-831885314).  I did this and found that the content (body) is likely the reason the post content doesn't send as well.  It seems the word clouds I am making are being encoded as text.  I assumed that this would be taken care of by setting:

```
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, warning = FALSE,
    base.url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/wordpress/",
    base.dir = "C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/Public/wordpress/")
```

...as Yihui suggests in the [wordpress demo](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/).  This does not seem to be the case. How might I send this blog post and keep it automated (i.e. not manually save a graphic and upload)?

Here is the script I use after making the weodpress script:

```
options(WordpressLogin = c(tylerrinker = "PASS"),
        WordpressURL = "http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php")
library(knitr)
knit2wp(file.path("C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/gradient_clouds_revisited/PRESENTATION", 
        "gradient_clouds_revisited.Rmd"), 
        title = 'knitr2wordpress and gradient_cloud Revisited', shortcode = TRUE)
```

Also note that the contents of the wordpress script can be seen at the bottom of this txt file:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/Errors/post.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base.url` and `base.dir` are options for `opts_knit$set()` instead of `opts_chunk` (I know this is very confusing); please take a closer look at the [demo page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/) and the [options page](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

```
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, warning = FALSE)

opts_knit$set(base.url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/wordpress/",
    base.dir = "C:/Users/trinker/Dropbox/Public/wordpress/")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  For those interested the blog post can be found [here](http://tiny.cc/kql7tw).  Thanks Yihui.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing it. It seems `opts_knit` and `opts_chunk` have been confusing quite a few people...

Comment: At the end of the blog I mention it and refer people back here but as you said a Jekyll bootstrap blog is much easier to deal with.  Just playing.

Comment: @TylerRinker Just think how you would _edit_ the WP post (it is indeed easy to publish a new post), and you will come to Jekyll in the next 5 minutes since you seem to have a lot time to play with cool technologies.

Comment: Yeah I have a blog set up through github but have been too lazy to get it aggregated with RBloggers as of yet.  With RStudio it's that much easier to blog with Jekyll.  And I actually don't have time but somehow find time for silliness :)  Thanks again for your help.